# Impedir que o usuario vote no mesmo Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Criei um sistema de votação, onde os usuários podem dar like/dislike nos capítulos dos livros postados no site. Segue minha action:

```
     public ActionResult Like(int id)
        {
            int iduser = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDUsuario"]);
            Voto v = new Voto();

            if (iduser != 0)
            {
                v.IdUsuario = iduser;
                v.IdCapitulo = id;
                v.Voto1 = true;
                db.Voto.Add(v);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Exibir","Capitulos");

}

            return View();

public ActionResult Dislike(int id)
        {
            int iduser = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDUsuario"]);
            Voto v = new Voto();

            if (iduser != 0)
            {
                v.IdUsuario = iduser;
                v.IdCapitulo = id;
                v.Voto1 = false;
                db.Voto.Add(v);
                db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Exibir","Capitulos");
            }


            return View();
```

Porém, quero impedir que o usuario vote no mesmo capitulo varias vezes. Aonde, e como eu poderia fazer essa verificação?

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia criar um flag (variável booleana) para marcar se aquele usuário já deu o voto nesse capítulo. Para isso você teria que criar uma nova tabela que armazena o ID do Usuário e um ID do capítulo, toda vez que o usuário votar você grava nessa tabela. Na próxima vez que o usuário for votar, você verifica se já existe registro nessa tabela, se houver, significa que ele estará votando novamente.

Esse foi o como.

Mas você também perguntou sobre "Aonde", portanto sugiro que você desenhe fronteiras e camadas no seu código. É de comum conhecimento que acessar o banco direto da camada de apresentação não é uma boa prática. O ideal é que você isole essas regras de negócio (em um projeto separado), assim você pode reaproveitá-las quando necessário.

É muito comum encontrar sistemas divididos em 3 camadas. Caso você seja novo no assunto, sugiro começar por este link:

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_em_tr%C3%AAs_camadas

Answer (score 1):

Tente recuperar o voto antes de exibir o link like/dislike na tela. Se ele já votou, exiba um link mostrando que ele já fez.
Também, permita ele mudar o voto dele. Novamente precisará recuperar a informação no db (com o id do usuário e id do capítulo) e trocar o valor do voto.